# Get more information from django/python or server log

Tags: python, django, redhat, django-csrf, dajaxice

I'm trying to debug a "POST" request error but I do not have enough information. Thus I need help to figure out more.

I get the following error in my `tail -a`. This is the only thing it displays in tail and of inside the log itself. I assume that tail does not have `-v` for verbose.

```
==> python/logs/access_log-20131102-000000-EST <==
85.75.241.1 - - [02/Nov/2013:09:09:47 -0400] "POST /dajaxice/async.store_event/ HTTP/1.1" 500 16516 "http://example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36"
```

(I changed the example.com above with the original)

Where should I search to get additional information about this 500 error in the log files? Can I force python tell more?

In local server I get the following which does not tell something particular either.

```
[02/Nov/2013 14:22:15] "POST /dajaxice/async.store_event/ HTTP/1.1" 200 24
```

Finally are the codes `16516` and `24` tell me something particular in `500 16516` and `200 24` respectively? I know that 500/200 are the http codes but what are the others?

Comment: How about opening the page in a browser with `debug = True` in your settings.py? That's the default debugger. It's usually enough

Comment: You can configure django to put complete error information in logs for any errors. `500` is server error, so if you have debug enabled you will get django's debug page with all request info.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking in the access log. Errors, not surprisingly, are logged in the error log - you should look there for more detail.

(The second value is the number of bytes in the response.)

Answer (score 0):

I know, one should not use `debug = True`on a live server, but if it is the only way to hunt down a bug, ou should consider swithing it on for a few minutes to get more information.

Furthermore, the django debug-toolbar can be of help, e.g. it can disply addidtional logging messages which are not written to file but raised using

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__) # Get an instance of a logger __name__ will be your app name
```

and use e.g.

```
logger.debug(str(form.cleaned_data))
```

Or you write your own logger:

```
"""Logger to File"""
file_logger = logging.getLogger("file_logger")
file_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(message)s')
handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, "log", "filelogger_log.log"), maxBytes=10000000, backupCount=5)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
file_logger.addHandler(handler)
```